# Display nested relation variable on resource index

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am developing a Laravel admin using Laravel Nova.
I have DB structure:

```
works
   id
   device_id
   work_type

devices
   id
   serial_number
   device_type_id

device_types
   id
   device_name
   brand_id

brands
   id
   brand
```

This is the Work model class

```
class Work extends Model {

    public function device() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( device::class );
    }

}
```

This is the Device model class

```
class Device extends Model {

    public function deviceType() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( DeviceType::class, 'device_type_id' );
    }

}
```

This is the DeviceType model class

```
class DeviceType extends Model
{
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( Brand::class );
    }

}
```

**This is my actual Nova resource**

```
class Work extends Resource
{
    
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
                BelongsTo::make( 'Serial number', 'device', 'App\Nova\Device' )->searchable()
         ];
    }
}
```

On the Laravel Nova "Works" index page, I would like something like that:
| Work ID  | Serial number  | Device type | Brand   |
| -------- | -------------- | ----------- | ------- |
| 1234     | 12345678901234 | S20         | Samsung |
| 2345     | 99999999999999 | S21         | Samsung |

I have no idea how to display "Device type" and "Brand" columns.

These columns also should be sortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display `device_type` and `brand` as columns on your `Works` index page is fairly simple. Just add the `device_type` and `brand` as custom attributes to your `Works` model. Afterwards, you can access them in your Nova resource.

**Work model**

```
class Work extends Model {

    public function device() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( device::class );
    }

    public function getBrandAttribute(): string
    {
        return $this->device->deviceType->brand->brand ?? '';
    }

    public function getDeviceTypeAttribute(): string
    {
        return $this->device->deviceType->device_name ?? '';
    }

}
```

**Work Nova Resource**

```
class Work extends Resource
{
    
    // Override indexQuery to your liking, joining tables
    public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
    {
        return $query->join('devices', 'devices.id',  '=','works.device_id')
            ->join('device_types', 'device_types.id', '=', 'device_type_id')
            ->join('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'brand_id')
            ->select([
                'works.*', 
                'devices.device_type_id as device_type_id', 
                'devices_types.device_name as device_name', 
                'devices_types.brand_id as brand_id', 
                'brands.brand as brand'
            ]);
    }

    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            BelongsTo::make( 'Serial number', 'device', 'App\Nova\Device' )
                ->searchable(),

            Text::make('Device name', 'device_name')
                ->onlyOnIndex()
                ->sortable(),

            Text::make('Brand', 'brand')
                ->onlyOnIndex()
                ->sortable(),
         ];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, sorting is not out-of-the-box possible with Laravel Nova on these custom attributes, since the sorting is done on Database level.

Alternatively, you could try and updating the `indexQuery` function as [described here](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/85). There might be packages out there that add this functionality.

**Edit**

I have tinkered around with this in one of my own projects, it does seem to work by overriding the `indexQuery`. However, I do not have the models set-up the way you do so I did not test my answer. I also do not know how well this performs on large scale. See example above, and let me know if it works. Btw, you can remove the `custom attributes` from your model if you decide to override the `indexQuery` method.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a charm with little tweaks :)

Comment: I changed only this:
`->select(
                'works.*', 
                'devices.device_type_id as device_type_id', 
                'device_types.device_name as device_name', 
                'device_types.brand_id as brand_id', 
                'brands.brand as brand'
            )`

Comment: Great! I will update the answer accordingly. Of course you needed all fields of works. How well does this perform? And does pagination still work as expected? I guess it should, but I am curious!

Comment: Everything seems to be working! Pagination, custom filters (by device type, device name) and exporting to Excel (using external package) work as it should. Thanks again for your help.